# OBIEE date prompt clearing results in query with null value

Tags: sql, datepicker, oracle10g, prompt, obiee

I have a Dashboard with a date prompt which initially presents all the data in the answer. Then, if I choose a specific date, it presents only data for that date. The problem is, if that date is manually deleted in the prompt, that results in a query passing a NULL value for the date (View Display Error)

```
A datetime value was expected (received "").
```

I've been trying to apply a conditional filter but without success.

```
CASE
  WHEN '@{Date1}' = '' THEN
    "X".VALUE_DATE > TIMESTAMP '1900-01-01 00:00:00'
AND
    "X".VALUE_DATE < TIMESTAMP '2999-01-01 00:00:00'
  ELSE
    "X".VALUE_DATE = VALUEOF("Date1")
END
```

Date1 is the variable set in the prompt.

Comment: Maybe what I've been trying isn't the best approach, so a simpler question: is it possible to give a default value to a prompt after it is manually deleted ?

Comment: Have you defaulted the date prompt to a variable, for e.g., current date?